# Torsion group and torsion subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know the exact definition of torsion group.
But the definition of torsion "sub"group is confusing me.

1. A subgroup which is torsion.
2. A collcection of all elements in G whose order is finite.

Which of the two is correct definition of torsion subgroup? The difference between two is that 1. need not to contain "all" elements of finite order.

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

The point is, the set of *all* torsion elements need not be a subgroup. The possibly simplest example is provided by the infinite dihedral group $D$.

In fact if you realise $D$ as the following set of bijections over the integers, the group operation being compositon, 
$$
\{ x \mapsto a x + b : a = \pm 1, b \in \mathbb{Z} \}, 
$$ 
you see that the torsion elements are precisely those with $a = - 1$, which have all period two. But the product of two distinct such elements is an element of infinite order.